# Export multiple functions in typescript package

Tags: typescript, npm, module, package

I'm writing a npm package in Typescript which implements several functions.

At the moment, I'm importing all the functions in a file `index.ts` and re-export them immediately:

```
import { functionA, functionB } from "./file1";
import { functionC, functionD } from "./file2";
export {
  function A,
  function B,
  function C,
  function D,  
}
```

I can use them in other projects using `import { functionA } from "package";`

However I'd like to export these functions so that I can use the package like this in another project (without using a class):

```
import _ from "package"
const foo = _.functionA(...);
const bar = _.functionB(...);
```

This is similar to the implementation of Lodash. I've searched in many places but exporting stuff in typescript is quite confusing (for instance, `index.d.ts` in lodash has two exports for `_` and some `declare const`, `declare namespace` stuff...)

Comment: Consider using a namespace import for idiomatic reasons.

Comment: Consider putting the functions into a class and exporting the class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Export the default object with those properties:

```
const _ = {
  functionA,
  functionB
}

export default _;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

You can [import the module in variable using `import * as` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports)

```
import * as _ from './package';
_.functionA();
```